# Как задать timestamp в запросе к api литреса

Tags: c#, timestamp

Отправляю запрос к api Литреса для получения списка новых книг с определенной даты. Но проблема в том, что если в качестве чекпоинта указать время на час и более от текущего, то выдает ошибку

> Query signature is invalid: timestamp expired

А если меньше, то все хорошо, запрос возвращает xml с данными.

```
 string checkpoint = "2019-07-06 16:00:41";
            string timestamp = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(checkpoint).ToString();
            string sha = ComputeSha256Hash(timestamp + ":secret_key:" + checkpoint);
            string place = "place";

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "checkpoint", checkpoint },
           { "place", place },
           { "timestamp", timestamp },
           { "sha", sha }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://partnersdnld.litres.ru/get_fresh_book/", content);

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
    {   
        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }

    static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(string date_str)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(date_str, new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan diff = date - origin;
        return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
    }
```

Вот что по поводу чекпоинта написано в их инструкции:

> • checkpoint – время в формате ISO (например, 2017-12-06 19:35:39), с которого следует забирать новинки. Вы получите список новинок со временем большим или равным checkpoint и меньшим /fb-updates/@timestamp (см. описание XML ниже). Если вы хотите получать непрерывную ленту новинок, сохраняйте отданный вам сервером /fb-updates/@timestamp и в следующий раз используйте его в качестве checkpoint. Для получения полной базы (при первоначальной загрузке) используйте чекпойнт «2013-01-01 00:00:00»;

и

> Программисты Windows! Проверьте свои таймстампы на http://www.timestampgenerator.com/. Обратите внимание, что вычислять таймстамп из местного времени нельзя! Таймстамп считается по UTC и без сдвига летнего/зимнего времени. В Википедии есть множество подробностей по теории таймстампа, а также есть огромное количество исходников для любого языка, от Perl до PL/SQL.

Я проверял, мой код генерирует timestamp такой же, как и там, если указать нужное время.
Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Вы указываете `2019-07-06 16:00:41`, а сейчас по utc `17:44`

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.8) - не пойдёт? Вместо самописного кода.

Comment: @tym32167 а разве я не должен указывать время, с которого хочу получить список обновлений, а не текущее?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а это роли не играет, похоже. Разве что кода меньше. Значения возвращаются все равно идентичные, ошибка тоже никуда не делась.